# How to call those method which take reference type arguments using typemock

Tags: xunit, typemock-isolator

I am using 'Xunit + TypeMock' to make test cases.

Whenever I am trying to call the follow method

```
protected abstract void UpdateObject(K response, ref int id)
```

from my test method, I get an exception.

I am calling this method from my test method like this :

```
int referenceID=0;
var passedResonse=new class();
Isolate.Invoke.Method(_FakeObject, "UpdateObject", passedResponse, ref referenceID);
```

But the method does not get called and give me error.

Kindly let me know, how can I call such methods (UpdateObject) from a test method.

Thanks

Comment: Kindly give me any suggestion in the regard of above question. Any help will highly be appreciated. Thank

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? What are you trying to test?